Azure Adb2c External IDP Authentication Browser Back Button Click redirects to External IDP Again
We have AD B2C Authentication with .NET 8 MVC Web Application. We configured Open Id Provider with Custom Policy in Adb2c. The authentication is working successfully. But the problem is, after the External IDP successful authentication, the provider redirects to the web site. Now User clicks on browser back button, the site redirect to external idp, because the history is there in the window  (single and multiple click applicable). On multiple click adb2c shows bad request, because session is already exist in the browser window.
Info: we disabled the External IDP SSO login for force login every time, since adb2c manages the users session.
Web site => Adb2c + External IDP => Successful Authentication => redirects to adb2c => Redirects to Web Site => Web Site => Browser Back Button (Single Or Multiple click) <= External Idp or Adb2c Bad Request.
Is there any way to restrict the redirection to external idp or adb2c bad request, I tried the browser back button click disable, that didn't help.
is there any way to handle this adb2c bad request in asp.net core mvc.

What address is in the address bar when the 400 is produced? B2clogin? Do you have diagnostics configured in b2c for auth and session management?

on multiple click it is b2clogin and shows bad request, when I did research, if session there in the browser, this 400 will raise

There's a lot of reasons B2C can give a 400. In most cases it's due to custom policy configuration. If you click back in the browser once from your Web site, this is the same request being sent to b2clogin as was sent just after signing in through the external IdP (I assume this is Entra / Azure AD in your case)? There's a B2C log viewer plug in available for vs and vs code you can use which traces the entire journey as defined in the policy. Are you able to configure diagnostics and pinpoint the trace produced when a 400 is generated?
